# jquery background from image to color and back again

Tags: jquery

I have a html page, with jquery loaded.  It has no css at the moment.

It has a background image set as:

```
<body background="image1.gif">
```

I'm trying to change this to a color (say black) and back again to the image using onclick.

I've managed to set up the divs and all ok.  For changing color to color I used:

```
jQuery('body').css('background-color','black');
```

on another page, but that doesn't work here because i want to go from image to color and back again.

So, how can I change the background image to a flat color and back again with jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css and change the class instead:

The HTML:

```
<body class="image">
```

The CSS:

```
body.image{
  background-image: url('image.gif');
}
body.colour{
  background-color: black;
}
```

And for scripting:

```
$('body').addClass('colour').removeClass('image');
```

And back again:

```
$('body').addClass('image').removeClass('colour');
```

Comment: This works great once I click a twice, bu what do I do to show the image first when the page loads?  Basically, what to replace <body background="image1.gif">
 with?

Comment: Look at the update I made to the answer. And if it helps,  please mark it as answer ty :-)