# Using JQuery to toggle between styles

Tags: jquery, css

Good afternoon,

I am searching for a way to Toggle between styles:

Example:

I have two styles(classes), one makes the paragraph red and the other makes the paragraph blue. I only  want to use JQuery to call the styles, not to hold the styles itself.

So when I click a button, the paragraph turns red, when I click again, it turns blue.

Again, I would rather have the style separate and given class names and have JQuery switch between the two.

I have search the net but keep coming up with show/hide examples where the styles are embedded into the JQuery function.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Overmars

Hello everyone! This is what I did, as I mentioned I was simply trying to toggle between two styles. One styles does something, example: Make a text red or change an image and the other style makes another thing happened.

Thanks every one for your time a patience. You all do make a difference.

I found the answer in my JQuery Cook Book. Chapter 3. Event Handling Page 69. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.normalStyle').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('newStyle');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.

```
$('div.foo').toggleClass(function() {
  if ($(this).is('.blue')) {
    return 'red';
  } else {
    return 'blue';
  }
});
```

This example will toggle the `blue` class for `<div class="foo">` elements if their parent element is of class `red`; otherwise, it will toggle the `blue` class.

or even shorter:

```
 $('div.blue').toggleClass('red');
```

a toggled class outrules the initial color, (red class is just added) as used in:

```
 $('div.blue').click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('red');
 });
```

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DYAvb/)**

or with really pure class replacement (the blue is removed and the red is added and vv):

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red blue')
 });
```

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DYAvb/1/)**

Comment: I tried this but it's not switching: $('subContent a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('readMore readMoreClick')
 });

Comment: @Overmars: this works: http://jsfiddle.net/DYAvb/3/ please mind how the html AND the jQuery selectors are built, you obviously missed a dot before subcontent ;)

Comment: Yes I saw my type: Sorry about that. It should be. $('#subContent a').click(function() { $(this).toggleClass('readMore readMoreClick') }); I'll continue to mess with all these examples. Thanks again

Comment: So again just so I am clear, I am referring to switching the styles not the color, I only reference color as an example: Meaning if I was actually using colors, the colors would be attached to a style sheet, where do I placed the styles in your example that I am toggling? Because it is switching the color not the actual styles.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle on and off your class to change your text color.

```
$("#someButton").click(function(){
  $("#someP").toggleClass("makeRed");
});
```

**[Simple example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/GQJku/)**

Comment: I was only using text color as an example, but I understand what you mean, what I am trying to do is switch the styles, which would contained more then a text color but thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Look at this post pls.
[jquery background from image to color and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451163/jquery-background-from-image-to-color-and-back-again/5451198#5451198)

i hope it will help :-)

it is basicly the same as what I understand you are looking for.

In stead of changing between an image and a colour, you can make the styles red/blue.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need something like:

Styleswitch stylesheet switcher built on jQuery
http://www.kelvinluck.com/2009/07/jquery-styleswitch-now-with-toggle/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .aParagraph
        {
            width:700px;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:15pt;
            border: 3px inset green;
        }
        .blueParagraph
        {
            color:Blue;
        }
        .redParagraph
        {
            color:Red;   
        }

    </style>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        });



        function colorRed() {
            var P = $("#theParagraph");
            P.removeClass("blueParagraph");
            P.addClass("redParagraph");
        }

        function colorBlue() {
            var P = $("#theParagraph");
            P.removeClass("redParagraph");
            P.addClass("blueParagraph");

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="button" id="makeRed" onclick="colorRed();" value="Turn Red" />
    <input type="button" id="makeBlue" onclick="colorBlue();" value="Turn Blue" />
    <div id="theParagraph" class="aParagraph redParagraph">
         Good afternoon,

I am searching for a way to Toggle between styles:

Example:

I have two styles(classes), one makes the paragraph red and the other makes the paragraph blue. I only want to use JQuery to call the styles, not to hold the styles itself.

So when I click a button, the paragraph turns red, when I click again, it turns blue.

Again, I would rather have the style separate and given class names and have JQuery switch between the two.

I have search the net but keep coming up with show/hide examples where the styles are embedded into the JQuery function.

Any ideas will be appreciated! 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```