# Press button to "Bold" & press again to "Unbold"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript. I want to make a button in html using javascript. When user try to press the button
the specific <#id> is going to be "Bold" and press again to "Unbold".

How can I do this ? please refer any helping material.
Thanks !

Comment: When tackling new problems, it's a good idea to try and break them down into their components, so you can try to search for answers to them and solve one at a time. I'd suggest in the future, try posting your thoughts about how you've tried breaking this down already, so people can offer advice and guidance on how to do this more effectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the learning experience is vital, especially for Javascript, I'll guide you in the right direction.

First, you should look into [event binding](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/) and [mouse event handling](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) with jQuery. You can do some powerful stuff with this knowledge, including what you would like to do.

Second, look into basic jQuery [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/). It's not hard to learn the simple CSS-based selectors that you can use to select your desired `id`.

Third, look at the [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css) function of jQuery, which falls under jQuery's [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/) category. You can use this to set different properties of elements, including font weight.

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing, you are trying to build something like RTE, So, applying class to give bold effect would be better and efficient solution to this.

It can be done as simple as this

```
$(".boldtrigger").click(function() { //boldTrigger being the element initiating the trigger
    $(".text").toggleClass("bold");  //text being the element to where applied to it.
});
```

CSS

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S9qDD/)

Answer (score 2):

here's another question that uses the .toggleClass for a vice versa effect. you need to create a class for that certain element since it adds and switches classes back and forth.

[Using JQuery to toggle between styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010790/using-jquery-to-toggle-between-styles)

---

for a one way change:

```
$('button_selector').on('click',function(){
    $('item_to_bold_selector').css('font-weight','bold');
});
```

references for this:

- [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for event handling
- [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for adding styles on the go

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to have the CSS selector class in a CSS file; apply a class on click and again when you unclick. Something like -> $("button").on("mousedown mouseup", function(){
$(this).toogleClass("boldClass");
});, and in the CSS .boldClass{ font-weight: bold; }

Comment: yup, i considered that. i forgot the OP wants a toggle. i found another resource that addresses his question.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery's [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) method should take care of this.

```
$('#foo').toggle(function() {
    $('#bar').css('font-weight', 'bold');
}, function() {
    $('#bar').css('font-weight', 'auto');
});
```

When you click `#foo`, it will do the next function in sequence, so this is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

here is the code to bold & unbold text

```
  <div id="contentDiv">

  content of the page.

  </div>
 <input type="button" value="Bold" id="font-button"></input>​

jQuery("#font-button").on("click",function(){

   var button = $(this);
   var contentDiv= $("#contentDiv");

  if(button.val() == "Bold"){

    contentDiv.css("font-weight","bold");
    button.val("UnBold");

  }else{

      contentDiv.css("font-weight","normal");
       button.val("Bold");
 }
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mqyMA/4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button_selector').on('click',function(){
  var itemToBold = $('item_to_bold_selector');
  if (itemToBold.css('font-weight') == 'bold') {
    $('item_to_bold_selector').css('font-weight','normal');
  } else {
    $('item_to_bold_selector').css('font-weight','bold');
  }
});
```

Based off of Joseph's answer, but with the unclick criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this post with jQuery I assume you are looking for a jQuery approach.

If you want to use a CSS class to add the bold style, I recommend you look at using toggleClass: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Lots of samples on that page...

Answer (score 1):

I like using `toggleClass()` ([API reference](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/))

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#element").toggleClass("bold");
});
```

If it has ".bold" when clicked it will unbold and vice versa.