# HTML and Javascript button to make text in a textarea bold and unbold, Possibly using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, formatting, textarea

I currently have a button that makes the text in a textarea bold it uses

```
<a href="#" class="stylingButtons" type="button" onclick="boldTextArea()" value="Bold Text"}>
 <img alt='Bold Button' src='BButton.gif' border='4' width="90px" >
</a>
```

for the HTML section and

```
function boldTextArea(){
document.getElementById("TextArea").style.fontWeight="bolder";;
}
```

for the javascript

Is there anyway I can edit this coding so that once the text in the text area is already bold, I could click again for it to become unbold?
I'm really not keen on the idea of using jQuery as I have never had any experience with it, but I am open to to suggestions in this format?

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use jquery , here is a quick'n'dirty javascript

```
function boldText(){
    var target = document.getElementById("TextArea");
    if( target.style.fontWeight == "bolder" ) {
        target.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    } else {
        target.style.fontWeight = "bolder";
    }
}
```

should work just fine.
this is the basic way of switching from bold to normal and back i guess.

also notice the DOUBLE ";" in yout JS.

hope this helps.

g.r. Ace

---

**UPDATE**

here is the jQuery version to change ( toggle ) the text size ( or any other css attribute ) on each click..

```
$("#textboxid").click( function(e) {
    if( $(this).css("font-size") == "12px" ) {
        $(this).css("font-size", "14px")
    } else {
        $(this).css("font-size", "12px")
    }
});
```

replace the css attribute to yout likes if you want to change any other attributes.

Comment: Please could you edit your coding, so it is jquery instead of javascript

Comment: and I was looking for text size instead of making bold

Comment: also you should be more specific, you said that you want to bold and unbold the text...

Answer (score 0):

I just did this on a site of mine and found the answer here:

[Press button to "Bold" & press again to "Unbold"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528466/press-button-to-bold-press-again-to-unbold%5C)

Hope this helps.