# Jquery toggle action

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using JQuery to toggle between styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010790/using-jquery-to-toggle-between-styles)

When I say toggle I don't mean the toggle() function. I change the css of an item to whatever on a click function, I want to click the item again and revert to the original css.

```
 $("#item").click(function(){
      $("#item").css("border-color", "#A8402A");
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of modifying styles inline, just use a class:

**CSS**:

```
.active {
    border-color: #A8402A;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('#item').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zjE3x/1/**

Comment: thanks a ton, I wish I had heard about the toggleClass function earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you mean the `.toggleClass()` function

Just do

```
$("#item").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("newClass");
});
```

where `.newClass` contains the styles you want to add/remove, i.e.

```css
.newClass{
    border-color: #A8402A;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). It will let you set your styles with css classes and then swap them dynamically from your jQuery.